# 'Yet ... yet ... , yet ...' construct

Tags: grammar

> [Source](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4329/why-isnt-please-help-on-our-titular-stoplist)
>
> *Yet* still we have a problem filter *yet* no other, *yet* I do not understand why.

Can anyone explain the meaning of those three 'yet' distinguishing, if any, their differences?

Answer (score 1):

Yet is used in a negative sentence or in a question to show that something has not happened up to now. To my knowledge, there is no yet,...yet construction, and certainly no yet...yet,...yet.

I'm not sure if "a problem filter" is an article-adjective-noun, but I will treat it as that.

> Yet still we have a problem filter yet no other

the second *yet* is a redundant use of yet, and should best be avoided. A better construction would be

> Yet still we have a problem filter but no other (substituting *but* for the second *yet*)

Your second phrase

> yet I do not understand why

Alone this would stand quite well, but together

Yet still we have a problem filter but no other, yet I do not understand why

Again, there is no yet,...yet construction, therefore one of the _yet_s needs to be eliminated or replaced.

> We still we have a only a problem filter, yet I do not understand why.

This imparts the idea you are trying to express, but it can be done still better.

> I do not understand why we still have a only a problem filter.